# Why in Sharepoint Store, I cannot ADD an App?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

When I want to Add an application such as Nintex, from Sharepoint Store,
I receive a message which says: "Sorry, apps are turned off. if You know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps".

Please tell me what is the problem.
 my second question is that, when  using the SharePoint store, Internet access must be available or not?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your first question first: The error you are posting is just a generic message that can be displayed because of several causes. Please take a look at your ULS logs and tell us which is your issue in detail.

Here the solution to two of them based on ULS information:

1) [App Management Shared Service Application Proxy not installed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/850ea411-944b-4da8-9b35-f121f19adf67/sorry-apps-are-turned-off-if-you-know-who-runs-the-server-tell-them-to-enable-apps?forum=sharepointadmin)

2) [The site subscription name SITEURL does not exist](http://blogs.technet.com/b/harmeetw/archive/2013/01/03/sharepoint-2013-you-receive-quot-sorry-apps-are-turned-off-if-you-know-who-runs-the-server-tell-them-to-enable-apps-quot-when-trying-to-add-apps-on-host-header-site-collection.aspx).

I don't think you have a conectivity problem, but a configuration one. Let us know.